# Getting 'Function components cannot be given refs' warning when using SVG file as ReactComponent with forwardRef()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an issue using an SVG file as a ReactComponent. I received the following error message:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

After struggling with type errors, I applied React.forwardRef() to my code, but I still received the same error in the console of my browser. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone give me some advice on what to do? Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef, SVGProps } from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as DataBaseImage } from '../../../assets/images/database--animated.svg';
import { ReactComponent as HighlightImage } from '../../../assets/images/highlight--animated.svg';

interface Props extends SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> {
  title?: string;
}

const DatabaseImageF = forwardRef<SVGSVGElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return <DataBaseImage {...props} ref={ref} />;
});

const HighlightImageF = forwardRef<SVGSVGElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return <HighlightImage {...props} ref={ref} />;
});

DatabaseImageF.displayName = 'Database';
HighlightImageF.displayName = 'Highlight';

const TaskStatus = () => {
  const databaseRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
  const highlightRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    databaseRef.current?.pauseAnimations();
    highlightRef.current?.pauseAnimations();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <DatabaseImageF ref={databaseRef} />
      <HighlightImageF ref={highlightRef} />
    </div>
  );
};


export default TaskStatus;
```

Comment: Based on your link, it seems like the bundler requires some additional SVG configurations. However, I am actually using Vite instead of Webpack, so I will need to find a corresponding solution for Vite. Thank you for your helpful advice.

Comment: But the problem is the same, right? I mean you want to manipulate SVG that is imported from a file using ref in react? For myself, I just canceled this whole idea and simply pasted the content of the SVG into the code, as normal react element.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested in the link and worked for me. The error has gone away! Setting `svgrOptions: { ref: true }` resolved the issue in Vite as well. Additionally, I believe that copying and pasting the complete content of the SVG into the code would also work.
Thank you very much for your help, it was greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest to close as duplicate then